# how do we provide coldfusion's session value in to triggers in mysql5?

Tags: mysql, triggers, coldfusion-8

while implementing triggers in mysql5 can i pass any session value that is in my coldfusion application (like- userName, createdBy etc) .

```
CREATE TRIGGER Users_After_Insert
AFTER insert ON users
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO auditlog (RequisitionID,ApplicantID,ColumnName,OldID,NewID,Description,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
values
(0,0,'',0,0,CONCAT('New user with UserID ',new.UserID,' is created.'),
 session.userName, curdate()
);
```

in above query i have to provide "session.userName" value to "CreatedBy" column of auditLog table because "CreatedBy" column is not in "user" table thats why i have to provide it from coldfusion session.

if some one could please help to solve this problem it would be greately appreciated.

Thanks
Yugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) and use this one in your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Users_After_Insert
AFTER insert ON users
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO auditlog (RequisitionID,ApplicantID,ColumnName,OldID,NewID,Description,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
values
(0,0,'',0,0,CONCAT('New user with UserID ',new.UserID,' is created.'),
 @userName, curdate()
);
```

before you execute the INSERT, you first have to set the username:

```
SET @userName = 'Shooter';
INSERT INTO ...;
```

But why don't you use a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-views.html) for this? With a trigger, things can go wrong, you could forget to set the variable.